# ls conditional in a linux script for loop

Tags: linux, sh, ls

I'm trying to create a simple `for` loop that will take all the outputs of an `ls` command and put each output into a variable. so far i have

```
for i in ls /home/svn
do
    echo $i
done
```

but it gives me an error.

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-loop-over-file/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the `ls` needs to be executed:

```
for i in $(ls ...); do
  echo $i
done
```

Also, you might want to consider shell globbing instead:

```
for i in /home/svn/*; do
  echo $i
done
```

... or `find`, which allows very fine-grained selection of the properties of items to find:

```
for i in $(find /home/svn -type f); do
  echo $i
done
```

Furthermore, if you can have white space in the segments of the path or the file names themselves, use a while loop (previous example adjusted):

```
find /home/svn -type f|while read i; do
  echo $i
done
```

`while` reads line-wise, so that the white space is preserved.

Concerning the calling of `basename` you have two options:

```
# Call basename
echo $(basename $i)
# ... or use string substitution
echo ${i##*/}
```

To explain the substitution: `##` removes the longest front-anchored pattern from the string, `#` up to the first pattern match, `%%` the longest back-anchored pattern and `%` the first back-anchored full match.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `ls` to go over files in this case, the following will do the job: `for i in /home/svn/*; do echo $i; done`

Comment: that works nice! i guess the final question is using basename basically i'm trying to use basename $i to get the name of the end of that directory isolated but it always print out

basename $i

when i do echo basename $i

Comment: @GwFiles: `basename` is a command, so is `echo`. So don't do both, just say `for i in /home/svn/*; do basename $i; done`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to assign the output of the ls command to i, so you need to enclose it in backticks or the $() operator:

```
for i in $(ls /home/svn)
do
    echo $i
done
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're doing it wrong in the first place.

```
for i in /home/svn/*
do
  echo "$i"
done
```